# Mathematica output doesn't work as input

Tags: output-formatting

Sometimes when I do, for example, a series expansion Mathematica gives me output that it won't take as input. For example if I do a series expansion:

```
Series[Hypergeometric2F1[a,x,y,z], {a,0,0} ]
```

produces:

```
Out[xx]= 1+ a Hypergeometric2F1^(1,0,0,0)[0,x,y,z] + O[a]^2
```

If I literally then click on this cell and evaluate it as input, or alternatively cut and paste this term into another input line and evaluate it returns the following error:

```
Syntax::sntxf: "(" cannot be followed by "1,0,0,0)".

Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .
```

So it doesn't seem to like the exact form as input that it just gave me as output. What gives?

EDITS:

1) I apologize for the formatting errors in the posting and the confusion that resulted, that should be fixed now. Thank you to those that pointed them out.

2) I have tried the suggestions to use `InputForm[%]`-the thing this, the expressions I am dealing with are very long, and when I put it into input-form they become unwieldy. I would prefer a way to retain the standard-form expression and manipulate that - but this might be impossible (it seems like it is impossible).

Thanks for the help so far anyway.

Comment: This indicates that you took derivatives in the wrong way somewhere. To track it down, you have to provide a minimal example of the code that produced this output line.

Comment: Some types of output can't be interpreted as input if you re-type them yourself.  One example would be $f^{(1,0)}[x]$.  However, when these are produced as output, they usually contain hidden information (in the form of a `TagBox`) that allows the system to interpret them again without ambiguity, even if you copy and paste them *in full*.  Try for example evaluating `Derivative[1, 0][f][x]` to produce such an output.  If you copy and paste them *partially*, or edit them, this information may get lost.

Comment: Please include Mathematica-Code as `Code` in your post. Click on the help button in the editor to see how this works.

Comment: `HypergeometricF1`
 isn't a Mathematica function. Do you mean `Hypergeometric2F1`?

Comment: If I type `?HypergeometricF1` I get `Symbol HypergeometricF1 not found` (MMa 8.0.4). So I think, you have created this symbol somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried highlighting the bracket of the output cell and then use "Edit -> Copy As -> Input Text"?

Comment: @Michael There's a bug in that, unfortunately ... the copied input text might not be pasteable ... (in certain situations)

Comment: @Szabolcs Where can I find more information about this bug?  Is there a post on that here?

Comment: The safest method to copy previous output is to use the key combo Shift+Ctrl+L; that way, any (invisible) formatting is preserved.

Comment: @MichaelWijaya http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/inconsistent-initial-and-boundary-conditions#comment17238_6135

Comment: Yo... someone else edited it that way and I can't figure out how to fix it in a timely fashion right now.

Comment: The error is because the list 0,1,0,0 is wrapped in round brackets rather than curly brackets. But Mathematica shouldn't normally produce output looking like that. Can you try evaluating `$Post=.` and then try again?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries:Could you tell how to run this [code](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=66031715C5F84356!665&authkey=!ANiInNdrbAbGljw&ithint=file%2ctxt) using [Wolfram Mathematica Online](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/online/).I get this `" « Graphics ‘ Animation ‘ " is incomplete; more input is needed ` while evaluating the code.

Comment: @justin This is not actually the place to ask about totally unrelated questions, but from what I can see on my iPhone it looks like you're using the wrong type of quote. Also you should use << as 2 characters not a single one. Additionally, you might not be using a package that is appropriate for the version you're using.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries:Okay.I've done as JasonB [said](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114933/creating-new-list-by-comparing-2-lists-elements/114937#comment311821_114937) but I'm getting `the peak memory limit of computer has reached` while using Mathematica online.It might be because I'm using trial version of [Wolfram Mathematica Online](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/online/).

Answer (score 3):

Use `InputForm` to get something you always can copy&paste:

```
Series[Hypergeometric2F1[\[Epsilon], x, y, z], {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]//InputForm
(*
==> SeriesData[\[Epsilon], 0, {1,
    Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][x, 0, y, z]}, 0, 2, 1]
*)
```

If you want it as normal expression, use `//Normal//InputForm` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the power series into a normal expression using

```
Series[Hypergeometric2F1[\[Epsilon],x,y,z], {\[Epsilon],0,1}]//Normal
```

Comment: Actually I did this in the actual code myself but it doesn't help. I just left it out here. As you can see from the errors the problem is with the (0,1,0,0). Thanks for the help though.