# Creating new list by comparing elements of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have two Lists (Not equal length). Both contain random numbers between `0` to `5000` (or another max limit):

```
A= {1000, 450, 50, 4100, ...,670}

B={500, 10, 4561, 2000, ...}
```

I would like to take each number from List `A` and compare it to all numbers in List `B`.

If the absolute value of `B` is smaller than `A` I will count it. If not I will not count it.

For example, in the Lists above, we start with `1000` in List A and compare it to all numbers in B, `500<1000`, `10<1000`... I will count all numbers that are smaller than `1000` and Build a new List `C` that contains  integers which represents the amount of all numbers that were smaller than `1000` (here only `2`), `450` (only `1`), `50` (`0`), `4100` (`3`)...

In the next step I return the same procedure for `450` etc.

So `C={2,1,0,3….}`

Can someone help me and show me a way?

Comment: `Map[Count[list2, x_ /; x < #] &, list1]` should get you started. If lists are huge, there are more efficient ways...

Comment: @Danny - all your questions seem very similar: making  `listC` from `listA` and `listB`

Answer (score 11):

Between Jason's and ciao's in terms of performance:

```
Length[listB] - Total[UnitStep[listB - # & /@ listA], {2}]
```

Comment: That's pretty, +1!

Comment: Gotta hit the hay, late here - but you'll need to adjust it for lists not of the same length, it does not like them as written.

Comment: @ciao fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
listA = RandomInteger[1000, 10]
listB = RandomInteger[1000, 10]
```

> Out[112]= {33, 651, 45, 947, 743, 964, 292, 182, 468, 563}
>
> Out[113]= {739, 127, 687, 104, 840, 990, 475, 455, 4, 878}

```
First@First@Position[Sort@Join[{#}, listB], #] - 1 & /@ listA
```

> Out[116]= {1, 5, 1, 9, 7, 9, 3, 3, 4, 5}

Comment: Try these with large lists (say 50K elements each)...  OP perhaps might specify if performance matters or if lists are beyond trivial sizes...

Comment: @ciao I did, and the `Count` and `LengthWhile` methods are drastically slower.  I'll post the timing if you think it's useful

Comment: @JasonB:Could you tell how to run this [code](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=66031715C5F84356!665&authkey=!ANiInNdrbAbGljw&ithint=file%2ctxt) using [Wolfram Mathematica Online](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/online/).I get this `" « Graphics ‘ Animation ‘ " is incomplete; more input is needed ` while evaluating the code.

Comment: [hmmm](https://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/62129338.jpg)......  I would remove that first line, ``« Graphics‘Animation‘ ``, then I would replace the last line with `ListAnimate[film]`  - never used MMA online, but it works in the desktop version

Comment: I meant these will *all* be slow...

Comment: @JasonB:Sorry but it's saying `the peak memory limit of computer has reached ` while using Mathematica online.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a quck-and-dirty for lists of non-trivial size. There are some other ways perhaps faster, but more details on list composition would be useful before I spend further time.

```
With[{u = Union@#1}, 
   Replace[#1,AssociationThread[u -> Ordering[Ordering[Join[u, #2]]][[;; Length@u]] - 
                                Range@Length@u], 1]] &[list1, list2]
```

Results of a quick benchmark, taking successively longer slices of two 10K long lists (usual loungebook performance caveats...):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using Jason's data

```
a = {33, 651, 45, 947, 743, 964, 292, 182, 468, 563};
b = {739, 127, 687, 104, 840, 990, 475, 455, 4, 878};

Count[b, x_ /; x < #] & /@ a
```

{1, 5, 1, 9, 7, 9, 3, 3, 4, 5}

Answer (score 2):

Using Jason's data:

```
a = {33, 651, 45, 947, 743, 964, 292, 182, 468, 563};
b = {739, 127, 687, 104, 840, 990, 475, 455, 4, 878};
```

Using `Compile`:

```
cf = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {b, _Integer, 1}}, 
     Module[{result = ConstantArray[0, Length[a]]}, 
     Do[result[[i]] = Total[UnitStep[a[[i]] - b]], {i, Length[a]}];
     result], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]

cf[a, b] // RepeatedTiming

(*{6.57434*10^-6, {1, 5, 1, 9, 7, 9, 3, 3, 4, 5}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

An attempt was made at an answer like this, but it was wrong, deleted and I cannot comment to show the right way. So, I am adding it as an answer.

I am grabbing data from @Jason B.

```
a = {33, 651, 45, 947, 743, 964, 292, 182, 468, 563};
b = {739, 127, 687, 104, 840, 990, 475, 455, 4, 878};
```

and now

```
Count[False] /@ Outer[Less, a, b]
```

gives

> {1, 5, 1, 9, 7, 9, 3, 3, 4, 5}

and of course, equivalently, we have

```
Count[True] /@ Outer[Greater, a, b]
```